# Generate JSON with collection represented with indexed items

Tags: java, json, gson, fasterxml

Is there some library that can generate JSON object in which collection is represented as set of numbered items?

When using for example GSON library and have class like this:

```
`class Bus {
    List<Passenger> passengers;

    public Bus(List<Passenger> passengers) {
        this.passengers = passengers;
    }
}`
```

GSON generates JSON like this:

```
`{
    "bus":{
        "passengers":[
            {"name":"John","familiName":"Smith"},
            {"name":"Marry","familiName":"James"}
        ]
    }
}`
```

But what I am requested is to generate JSON in which collection is represented with items each of which having its index.
Like this:

```
`{
    "bus":{
        "passengers[0]":{"name":"John","familiName":"Smith"},
        "passengers[1]":{"name":"Marry","familiName":"James"}
}}`
```

I digged in GSON and FasterXML but could not find support for this functionality.
Does anybody know if there is some library supporting this?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: So does it have to be exactly like in your example or for example like `{"index": "1", "name": "John","familiName": "Smith"}`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that implements JsonSerializer to specify how you want it to be serialized.
And then register it when building your Gson:
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Bus.class, new BusAdapter()).create();

More info: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Writing-a-Serializer

Comment: Thank you,
This is the legal way indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible for you to create Map<String, Passenger> instead of List (if you don't want to write custom serializer and deserializer). And constructor for Bus will be like:

```
private Map<String, Passenger> bus = new HashMap<>();

public Bus(List<Passenger> passengers) {
      for (int i = 0; i < passengers.size(); i++){
           bus.put("passengers["+i+"]", passengers.get(i));
      }
}
```

For simple passenger only with name it looks like

```
{
    "bus":
    {
      "passengers[0]":{"name":"first"},
      "passengers[1]":{"name":"second"}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you,
It seems to be an elegant solution avoiding writing a serializer. I will try it :)